# add <div> to "each block" each 2 results with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a each block something like:

```
<% for f in @following %>
 <div class="span6">
  <%= f.name %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

html result:

```
<div class="span6"> John</div>
<div class="span6"> kevin</div>
<div class="span6"> Peter</div>
<div class="span6"> Andrew</div>
.
.
.
```

I want add a `<div class="row"></div>` each 2 results something like:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span6"> John</div>
 <div class="span6"> kevin</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="span6"> Peter</div>
 <div class="span6"> Andrew</div>
</div>
```

**I want show 2 results per/row. How can I do it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
<% @following.each_slice(2) do |followers| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% followers.each do |f| %>
      <div class="span6">
        <%= f.name %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Didn't know about each_slice! Thanks!