# New row every 3 items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to render my list of items 3 at a time so that they output in rows of three. I am current using

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
 <% @items.each do |f|%>
   <div class="item">
     <%= f.content %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which outputs all the rules in one 'row' -

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
   <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I want to be able to do is output a row for every three items returned, so -

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
   <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
   <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
       <div class="item">
     This is the content
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [add <div> to "each block" each 2 results with rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214665/add-div-to-each-block-each-2-results-with-rails-3)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Besides the aforementioned `each_slice`, Rails also has an [`in_groups_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) method that you can use like so:

```
<% @items.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <% group.each do |item| %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= item.content %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Pretty much the same as `each_slice`, except the scenario of needing to output blank divs becomes much cleaner like so:

```
<% @items.in_groups_of(3).each do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <% group.each do |item| %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= item.content if item %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`in_groups_of` pads missing items in the last group with `nil` by default, so it will make the last few iterations and the `if item` check will make sure it doesn't blow up by calling `content` on `nil`.

[`in_groups`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups) is another fun one to use for view formatting.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [each_slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) method:

```
<% @items.each_slice(3) do |array_of_3_items|%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <% array_of_3_items.each do |item|%>
        <div class="item">
          <%= item.content %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Additional note:** What if you wanted 3 div for the last row, even if the last row contains only 2 items? (i.e. the `@items` is a list of 5 items, the last row should output only 2 div).

The solution:

```
<% @items.each_slice(3) do |array_of_3_items|%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <% array_of_3_items.each do |item|%>
        <div class="item">
          <%= item.content %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <% (3 - array_of_3_items.length).times.each do |fake_div| %>
        <div class="item empty">
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, but Cades answer was the one I used.