# Inserting something in between every 3 topics at `<%= render @topics %>`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to insert some images in between my topics (one in between every 3 topics for the first 3 groups of topics -- ie. 3 images in total), but I'm confused as to where since my `forums/show.html.erb` only has `<%= render @topics %>` and not some sort of each loop that I could manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not looking for a very fancy ruby way to do it, just do it the dirty way:

```
<% @topics.each_with_index do |topic, index| %>
 <% if index != 0 && index%3==0 %>
    <%= render @ad %>
 <% end %>
 <%= render topic %>
<% end %>
```

or if your partial takes the entire array do that in your partial logic.  However if you want a fancy way, this solution will help you: [New row every 3 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528919/new-row-every-3-items)

Comment: Mighty fine -- thank you very much! Is there a way to limit this to the first 3 groups of 3 though? The reason being that AdSense only allows max 3 ads. I'm sorry, I should have put that in my question.

Comment: <% if index != 0 && index < 10 && index%3 == 0 %>

Comment: By the way Aditya, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?