# in_groups_of(3) but only for the first 3 groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Expanding on [New row every 3 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528919/new-row-every-3-items) -- I'm trying to insert ads in between my Forem (https://github.com/radar/forem) topics -- one in between every 3 topics for the first 3 groups of topics (3 ads in total).

**UPDATE**

I ended up with this thanks to the answer below, unfortunately it doesn't seem to pass on `test` as a valid local (can't find `topic` inside `forem/topics/topic`):

```
<% @topics.in_groups_of(3).each_with_index do |grouped_topics, index| %>
  <%= render partial: "forem/topics/topic", collection: grouped_topics %>
  <% if index < 3 %>
    <p>Ad</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Live test app** (click the big green `Run` button to test):

http://runnable.com/VFUNK2ho3Fpr8Fp2/forem-with-ads-in-between-topics

File in question: [`views/forem/forums/show.html.erb`](https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/rails4/app/views/forem/forums/show.html.erb)

Comment: do as `@comments.in_groups_of(3).first(3).each do`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in_groups_of` split your array into array of arrays, so that should be:

```
<% @comments.in_groups_of(3, false).each_with_index do |grouped_comments, index| %>
  <% grouped_comments.each do |comment %>
    ...
  <% end %> 
  <% if index < 3 %>
    <%= image_tag "selfie.jpg">
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but `selfie.jpg` should only be rendered in the first 3 groups of 3 comments. After that, the other comments should render normally without `selfie.jpg`.

Comment: Having a little bit of turbulence. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I wouldn't call a variable `test`. While rendering  collection you have a typo: `<%= render partial: "forem/topics/topic", collection: @grouped_topics %>`, and should be `<%= render partial: "forem/topics/topic", collection: grouped_topics %>` (do not pass `grouped_topics` as an instance variable).

Comment: Thanks! Now both of those methods act the same -- `undefined method` etc. for everything that has to do with `topic` in `views/forem/topics/_topic.html.erb`. Any chance you could try out the live app?

Comment: Yep, but the link you've provided does not seem to work. I mean http://runnable.com/VFUNK2ho3Fpr8Fp2/forem-with-ads-in-between-topics

Comment: Damn. Yeah, it's Runnable. They keep crashing every now and then. They should be back up within a few minutes, please hold.

Comment: Ok, try now if you will.

Comment: It's still down, at least for me. The issue is `undefined method topic` raised from within partial?

Comment: I've totally forgot to add. By typing `in_groups_of(3)` means that the last array is fulfilled with nil's if there are not enough elements. You need to use `in_groups_of(3, false)`.

Comment: By the way man, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?